# Проблема со скриптом javascript bot twitch!

Tags: javascript, бот, twitch

Написал скрипт чтобы отправлять сообщения в чат твич с акка. Когда я пишу в консоль сообщения в чате твича их нет.

```js
const tmi = require('tmi.js');  
  
// Конфигурация параметров   
const config = {  
    options: {  
        debug: true  
    },  
    connection: {  
        reconnect: true  
    },  
    identity: {  
        username: 'имя акка',  
        password: 'токен'  
    },  
    channels: ['канал']  
};  
  
// Создание клиента Twitch   
const client = new tmi.Client(config);  
  
// Подключение к серверу Twitch   
client.connect();  
  
// Обработка события подключения к чату   
client.on('connected', (address, port) => {  
    console.log(`Connected to ${address}:${port}`);  
});  
  
// Обработка команд отправки сообщений   
function sendMessage(channel, message) {  
    client.say(channel, message);  
}  
  
// Чтение ввода с консоли   
const readline = require('readline');  
const rl = readline.createInterface({  
    input: process.stdin,  
    output: process.stdout  
});  
  
// Ввод сообщения и отправка в чат   
rl.setPrompt('Введите сообщение: ');  
rl.prompt();  
  
rl.on('line', (line) => {  
    sendMessage('TARGET_CHANNEL', line);  
    rl.prompt();  
}).on('close', () => {  
    process.exit(0);  
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас такой канал есть? в настройках указан канал ['канал'], а вы пытаетесь отправить(если я правильно понял) в TARGET_CHANNEL